# No. of homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_n$ to $\mathbb Q$

Tags: group-theory

How many homomorphisms are there from $\mathbb Z_n$ to $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: Is there an element $g$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that the following holds? $$\underbrace{g+\cdots+g}_{n}=0$$

Comment: @angryavian: yes !!! , there is no such non-zero $g$ in $Q$ , thanks

Answer (score 3):

*Hint* If $\eta:G\to H$ is a morphism of groups, and if $x\in G$ has finite order say $|x|=k$, then $(\eta x)^k=\eta(x^k)=\eta 1=1$ so $\eta x$ has finite order, and $|x| \mid |\eta x|$. Now look at the elements of finite order of $\Bbb Q$ (is this additive or multiplicative here?)

Comment: (I'm not sure if the OP is thinking $\Bbb Q$ as an additive of multiplicative group. In the former case the only torsion elt is $0$, in the latter, there are two torsion elts.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are taking the operation to be addition in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\phi(0) = 0$, as is true for all homomorphisms.  Then:

- $\phi(1) = \text{something}$
- $\phi(1+1) = \phi(1) + \phi(1) = \text{something + something}$
- $\phi(1+1+1) = \cdots$

What happens when this process is iterated $n$ times?

Comment: Iterating $n$ times will results in $\phi(0)=$something, which is non-zero. Contradiction. So there is no homomorphism. Right?

Comment: @KushalBhuyan;No there is the zero homomorphism i.e. $\phi(x)=0\forall x$ and this is the only one

Comment: "No nontrivial homomorphism" as they say